# Does Spinning dancer has anything to do with your eyesight

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, vision, human-eye

I came across the [spinning dancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_Dancer) as part of the brain test to determine left brain vs right brain dominance.

[image]

I saw the dancer is turning clockwise. The other people around me saw it turning clockwise for the first time, but soon they got confused and said they saw it turning it in both direction.

I know the tips of how to see it anti clockwise, but no matter what I do I always see it clockwise. I have shown it to a number of people and all of them could see it spinning in both direction after looking at it for longer time.

I am the only person who has never see the dancer turning in both direction.

My question is does this has anything to do with my eyesight? I have very limited(almost blind) eyesight in my left eyes. This is from birth.

Does my visual impairment has anything to do with this or does this mean anything else?

Comment: It's very frustrating to me that I can only see her spin one way…

Comment: @canadianer Check the answer to see her spin the other way.. We'll just cheat.. No thanks necessary.. :P

Comment: Okay actually now my life is complete because she's going the other way. It really helps if you just focus on her lower foot. I actually scrolled the page up so I couldn't see the rest of the image.

Comment: When I first saw this it quickly started switching back and forth on me, then for me. However after reading your predicament I too found my perception stuck. Looking at image, I closed my eyes and imagined it spinning the other way. When I opened them what I saw matched my new perception. Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bit of background, this test was devised by Nobuyuki Kayahara and it was originally thought that it shows the dominance of one part of the brain to the other. This was later on discarded as a misconception ([reference](http://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/left-brain-right-brain-and-the-spinning-girl/)). It is now widely believed that the clockwise - counter-clockwise rotation is a phenomenon called Bistable perception ([Reference 1](http://greengabbro.net/2007/10/20/the-spinning-dancer-and-the-brain/) and [reference 2](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/22/14/6195.full)).

> Multistable perceptual phenomena are a form of perceptual phenomena in
>   which there are unpredictable sequences of spontaneous subjective
>   changes. While usually associated with visual perception, such
>   phenomena can be found for auditory and olfactory percepts. Famous
>   examples include the Necker cube, structure from motion, monocular
>   rivalry and binocular rivalry, but many more visually ambiguous
>   patterns are known. Since most of these images lead to an alternation
>   between two mutually exclusive perceptual states, they are sometimes
>   also referred to as bistable perception([reference 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multistable_perception) and
>   [reference 2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959438803000990)).

No, the fact that you can only see her turn clockwise has not got anything to with your vision (for the record, I have never been able to see the girl go counter- clockwise myself).

> Sometimes, a person will stare at an image and it will never reverse.
>   Dr. Toppino advises staring at one part of the image, such as the
>   foot, and most of the time it will eventually flip. In people who
>   can’t see the reversal, it may be that one underlying neural structure
>   is more dominant, but once someone finally manages to see the flip, it
>   will start to happen more often ([reference](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/04/28/the-truth-about-the-spinning-dancer/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0)).

[image]

This image would help you watch her rotate counter-clockwise.

[image]

Here she is spinning clockwise.

Comment: That blew up my mind. Now I can see her rotate in both direction!!! Thanks for the references.